# Cannot connect to LocalDB, file not found exception

Tags: c#, sql-server, app-config

here is the connection string

```
<add name="Tapo_ModelContainer" connectionString="metadata=res://*/filename.csdl|res://*/filename.ssdl|res://*/filename.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string='Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=APTapo;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFramework'" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

The Exception

```
System.Data.EntityException {"The underlying provider failed on Open."}
```

inner Exception

```
"A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)"
```

inner exception

```
"The system cannot find the file specified"
```

If i use the normal SqlConnection class, i can connect to the database.

Comment: Make sure the service is running in your machine .....

Comment: The inner exception tells you the problem it cannot connect to: `(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB` Take a look to: https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2012/  I guess the right datasource will be `localhost` or `.\SqlExpress\ ` And ensure the service is running

Answer (score 0):

It could be because of the permissions. 
in the Authentication section. If you can not write the correct connection string you can use Connect To Database option in Tools menu item and if Test Connection is ok then copy the connection string.

Comment: or make a textfile and rename it from .txt to .udl. Than doubleclick on it and you will have a form where you can build and test your connection string.